# Import from maven local

Tags: java, gradle, intellij-idea

I installed jar with library I need with this command:

```
mvn install:install-file 
-Dfile=/home/IdeaProjects/webstruct/build/libs/webstruct-0.0.2.jar 
-DgroupId=ru.xpendence 
-DartifactId=webstruct 
-Dversion=0.0.2 
-Dpackaging=jar 
-DgeneratePom=true
```

It's ok, I see library in .m2, & I add dependency to `build.gradle`:

```
compile group: 'ru.xpendence', name: 'webstruct',version: '0.0.2'
```

But when I try to use classes from library, for example, to extend from abstract class, it appears in IDEA helper:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

But when I try to import it, class not imports standart way, & IDEA can't recognize package:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

There is a library in dependencies:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Please, help me. I build jar with gradle build.

Comment: Can you try to reimport in IDEA IDE, there is an option to reimport.

Comment: What happens when you build from IDE (Build | Rebuild Project) or by Gradle from command line? When you navigate to class (Navigate | Class) do you see the package correctly?